# Rails Prelaunch + Devise + OmniAuth Facebook

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Has anyone got the Rails Prelaunch project: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-prelaunch-signup working with Devise+OmniAuth Facebook login: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview?

I'm able to login to Facebook and retrieve the info, however, when

```
sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
```

is called, it goes back to my login screen saying that the account hasn't been activated even though I was able to login before OmniAuth Facebook was implemented (Prelaunch requires account to be activated before login is allowed).

UPDATE:

I've been debugging more. I tried to login via just email. It seems like after the email login succeeds, it still tries to authenticate via Facebook using whatever's in the cookie.